# HttpURLConnection android not working at all lots of exceptions

Tags: android

I have this code but seems like there are errors for the import classes. Unhandled exception: java.net.MalformedURLException for URL , Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException for openConnection(), Unhandled exception: java.net.ProtocolException for setRequestMethod etc. What is wrong?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

 private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    String url = "https://www.server.com";
        try {

            URL myurl = new URL(url);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            StringBuilder content;

            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {

                String line;
                content = new StringBuilder();

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    content.append(line);
                    content.append(System.lineSeparator());
                }
            }

            System.out.println(content.toString());

        } finally {

            con.disconnect();
        }
```

}

Comment: Click on red lines and things will be sorted. I don't think try is parameterized method.  Looks wrong to me " try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) "

Comment: I clicked but nothing its not working!

Comment: Before finally add catch block

Comment: @SahilGoyal Thanks this was the issue if you want answer the question to accept it!

Comment: Don't Worry, Your Thanks is more than enough.